Use the same values in Chart.yaml and values.yaml for ArgoCD
I am deploying several components which have the same image tag and chart version. I want to keep all those versions in a single file, so either Chart.yaml or values.yaml is the source of truth.
For example, values could look like this:
global:
  versions:
    myAppVersion: &myAppVersion "123-321"

myApp:
  replicaCount: 1

  image:
    repository: http://docker-repo
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
    tag: *myAppVersion

and Chart.yaml:
apiVersion: v2
name: SomeApp
type: application
version: 1.0.0
dependencies:
  - name: myApp
    version: '{{ index .Values.global.versions "myAppVersion" }}'
    repository: '@helm-repo'

However it seems that variables are not allowed in Chart.yaml. Is there any other way to achieve this? Adding the ArgoCD tag because there might be additional limitations.
EDIT: there are several components: myApp1, myApp2, ...
